# Include parameters with URL in homebrew formula

Tags: homebrew

In a homebrew formula you can specify a resource to download with a URL like the following:

```
resource "other_files" do
    url 'https://some_server.com/action/download?file=somefile&other=info
    sha256 "..."
end
```

but that doesn't work, because homebrew has to escape the ? and & to be able to pass the URL to curl. So how can I properly pass parameters to a URL?

EDIT: Further investigation reveals that I mis-diagnosed the problem. In fact, the problem is that my url needs to set a session cookie, then redirect to the actual download. Using the `curl` command generated by homebrew, this means adding `-c cookie_store.txt` to the command line, after which the curl command works. So that completely changes the question.

Comment: It does work; Homebrew itself has formulae with resources that have `?` in their URL, e.g.: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/d3ae1317a8259b2553cd53b1dd78f33a6e062189/Formula/crash.rb#L10. Homebrew doesn’t do anything with those characters.

Comment: Ahh, I misdiagnosed the problem. Looking at what actually downloaded, it looks like it might be a problem with cookies being disabled - at least, that is the title of the page it got. So the question becomes "how can I enable cookies", which I have not yet researched.

Comment: I’m not sure about it, but it _looks_ like you could use something like `url "http://...", :cookies => {...}` according to this: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/0859115a2400b4548a52a8b67656601c46c64db5/Library/Homebrew/download_strategy.rb#L418

Comment: @bfontaine Close, but not quite. That gives me a 403 error when I try it. HOWEVER, if I take the command it uses, and replace the `-b` (load cookies) flag with a `-c` (save cookies to file) flag, it works. unfortunately, I'm not seeing anything in that code you linked where it might set the `-c` flag.

Comment: @bfontaine Ahhh, but setting the `-b` flag is good enough, as long as I get the rest of the URL correct. The 403 was due to a typo. So your suggestion DID resolve the issue for me. Thanks!